# caffe.set_mode_cpu() error in Caffe

Tags: cmake, gpu, cpu, deep-learning, caffe

I have built caffe with only cpu support. Is the command 'caffe.set_mode_cpu() ' only used when we have built with gpu support so that we can switch to cpu when needed? I thought I might need it just to make sure that Caffe is using my cpu but I guess the build takes care of that. Also is this command required even when I have built with cpu support only?

Error I get-

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
E1220 14:26:00.833413 17923 common.cpp:117] Cannot create Cublas handle. Cublas won't be available.
E1220 14:26:00.833684 17923 common.cpp:124] Cannot create Curand generator. Curand won't be available.
E1220 14:26:00.833871 17923 common.cpp:128] Cannot create cuDNN handle. cuDNN won't be available.
F1220 14:26:00.834089 17923 _caffe.cpp:61] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (35 vs. 0)  CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

[Problem posted on caffe users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/vP-y8ju92zY)

This is my output of 'ccmake ..' . It says that CPU_ONLY is off even after removing the comment on CPU flag. How do I make it build with CPU for sure?
[image: Output of ccmake ..]

To build Caffe, I used cmake .. instead of make as I got [convert_imageset.bin error](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2348). So I followed the instructions in the link and I got it to build properly.

Now I was looking at my cmake output and realised that the "CPU_ONLY" option was set to off. So i followed this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/ZejVbSP8oLU) where i used "cmake -DCPU_ONLY=ON" to set it ON.

But I'm still getting Cuda error even when cmake option "CPU_ONLY=ON" is there. I am not sure why it is still being built with GPU?

Looking at my cmake output again, I found this error-

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:85 (add_dependencies): The dependency target "pycaffe" of target "pytest does not exist.
```

Is this fine since anyways we have to do make pycaffe to build with python?

Comment: you are getting GPU errors. this makes no sense if you compiled with CPU_ONLY flag set... are you sure this is the case? is it possible you only compiled part of your caffe with the flag?

Comment: Hi Shai, i edited the question with my 'ccmake ..' output.

Comment: I usually edit the Makefile.config and use `make` instead of `cmake`...

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question now.

Comment: Clearly looks like you did not do a clean build, after making the changes in CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu Hi I'm still stuck at this. I am using Opencv 3.2.0 with python 3.4.3. I still get the target "pycaffe" not existing. Any idea how to solve this?